# NG2 Tree module not found after install on an Angular 2 new app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have install the ng2-tree plugin in a new Angular 2 app (rc4), but after following [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-tree). The plugin has been installed, and is on the node_modules folder.

I have tried to use it in this component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TreeModel, TreeComponent} from "ng2-tree";

@Component({
    selector: 'tree-side',
    templateUrl: '../../pages/tree-side.html',
    directives: [TreeComponent]

})
export class TreeSideComponent{
    private tree: TreeModel = {
        value: 'Programming languages by programming paradigm',
        children: [
            {
                value: 'Object-oriented programming',
                children: [
                    {value: 'Java'},
                    {value: 'C++'},
                    {value: 'C#'}
                ]
            },
            {
                value: 'Prototype-based programming',
                children: [
                    {value: 'JavaScript'},
                    {value: 'CoffeeScript'},
                    {value: 'Lua'}
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
}
```

But I get this error on the npm console:

```
404 GET /ng2-tree
```

I have modified the system.config.js with the following code, trying to find a workaround:

```
var map = {
   ...
    'ng2-tree':                   'node_modules/ng2-tree'
};
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    ...
    'ng2-tree':                   { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

But I get this error after:

```
Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-tree as "ng2-tree" from http://localhost:3000/app/pages/tree.component.js
```

Following the instruction of Thierry Templier I tried this other configuration. Including the configuration for the lodash plugin, cause this had the same problem as the ng-tree after fixing the ng-tree dependency.

```
 var map = {
...
        'ng2-tree':                   'node_modules/ng2-tree',
        'lodash':                   'node_modules/lodash'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
...
        'ng2-tree':                   { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'lodash':                   { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
```

But in this case I got:

```
[1] 16.08.08 12:04:09 404 GET /tree.component.html
[1] 16.08.08 12:04:09 404 GET /node-menu.component.html

Failed to load tree.component.html ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load tree.component.html
```

Apparently this is due to the relative path resolution, but in anycase does not correspond to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you missed the `main` property in the `packages` configuration for ng2-tree:

```
var packages = {
  ...
  'ng2-tree': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

Comment: I tried and after that I got this error on NPM: 16.08.08 11:49:55 404 GET /lodash. Should I do the same with this plugin ?

Comment: What do you mean by "on NPM"? Is it when you execute your application? If so, it seems that ng2-tree has the lodash dependency that needs to be configured in the SystemJS configuration...

Comment: I mean, running the project, I see that error on the console. On the browser inspector the error is:Error loading http://localhost:3000/lodash as "lodash" from http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-tree/src/tree.component.js. I have tried to to the same with the lodash plugin, and the error is other: Failed to load tree.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue when trying to load the TreeModule. I have solved this issue. The problem was with the `@angular/cli` version . In the `package.config` file inside `\node_modules\ng2-tree` change

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.1",
}
```

to

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "#####",// version of your @angular/cli(**You can find it from package.config file in the root folder**)
}
```